# Best data modelling approach to handle redundant foreign keys in a database about Surveys, Questions and Responses

Tags: database-design, erd

I am looking for advice on the best relational modelling approach to store surveys, questions, and responses.

I am looking for which of the two approaches below looks best, or an alternative approach to either.

I have at least these entities:

- question
- survey
- person

And at least these relationships:

- Each survey has 1 or more questions.
- Each question may be used in 0 or more surveys.
- Each person may take 0 or more surveys.

Here is where I run into trouble: **how to model the responses to survey questions made by a person.**

Here are two approaches I've considered, neither of which seems very good to me.  The diagrams here are greatly simplified to illustrate the issue.

**Approach 1:**
[image: Approach 1]

What I don't like about this approach:

- The `survey_person_question_response` table has two different columns that refer to a survey: `survey_question_survey_id` and `survey_person_survey_id`

  - It would be an error to have different `survey_id`'s referenced in one row for these two columns.  The survey_question must be from the same survey as the person took in survey_person. I can't see a good way to enforce this.
- It seems like what I am doing here is making a relationship between two relationships.  That feels wrong to me for some reason.

**Approach 2:**

Try to avoid two FKs from approach 1 that should refer to the same value...
[image]

What I don't like about this approach:

- There is no enforcement that the `question_id` and `survey_id` FKs are from a valid `survey_question` pair
- There is no enforcement that the `survey_id` and `person_id` FKs are from a valid `survey_person` pair

Any advice on:

- Whether one of these approaches is a typical approach
- The pros and cons of one of these approaches over the other
- A better way to arrange this data entirely

Would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As per my understanding of your specifications, your business environment involves a conceptual-level *ternary relationship*. In this regard, you need to define:

1. the relationship  (or *association*) type between the entity types *Person* and *Survey*;
2. the relationship type between *Survey* and *Question*;
3. the relationship type that establishes the connection between the two aforesaid relationship types and, as a consequence, between *Person*, *Survey* and *Question*, i.e., *Response* (a shorter name that simplifies interpretation, from my point of view).

So, I consider that you are on the right track with your *Approach 1*, although it requires some small (yet important) refinements in order to make it more accurate. I will detail such refinements and other relevant considerations in the following sections.

## Business rules

Let us expand the applicable business rules a bit and reformulate them in the following way:

- A *Person* registers in zero-one-or-many *Surveys*
- A *Survey* gets the registration of zero-one-or-many *Persons*
- A *Survey* is integrated by one-to-many *Questions*
- A *Question* integrates zero-one-or-many *Surveys*
- A *Question* receives zero-one-or-many *Responses*
- A *Response* is provided by exactly-one *Person* in the context of exactly-one *Survey*

**Expository IDEF1X diagram**

Then, I have created the IDEF1X<sup>**a**</sup> diagram that is presented in [Figure 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7a2bf.jpg), which synthesizes the business rules formulated above:

[image: Fig.1 Simplified Survey IDEF1X]

---

<sub><sup>**a**</sup> *Integration Definition for Information Modeling* ([IDEF1X](http://www.idef.com/idef1x.htm)) is a highly recommendable modeling technique that was established as a *standard* in December 1993 by the United States National Institute of Standards and Technology (*NIST*). It is solidly based on theoretical work authored by the *sole founder* of the [relational model](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=362685), i.e., [Dr. E. F. Codd](http://amturing.acm.org/award_winners/codd_1000892.cfm) and also on the [entity-relationship view](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=320440) developed by [Dr. P. P. Chen](http://awards.acm.org/award_winners/chen_6196475.cfm).</sub>

---

**The *PersonSurvey* relationship**

As I see it, the *PersonSurvey* relationship is required to provide a means of authorization so that a *Person* can take part in a given *Survey*. In this way, once a certain *Person* has been registered in a specific *Survey*, he or she is authorized to provide *Responses* to the *Questions* that integrate the respective *Survey*.

**The *SurveyQuestion* relationship**

I assume that the property (or attribute) called *suvery_question.question_number* in your diagram is used to represent the *Order* of presentation of a given *Question* instance with respect to a particular *Survey*. As you can see, I have denoted such property as *SurveyQuestion.PresentationOrder*, and I think that you should prevent that (i) two or more *Question.QuestionNumber* values share (ii) the same *PresentationOrder* value in (iii) the same *SurveyQuestion* occurrence.

To portray that need, I have included a composite ALTERNATE KEY (AK) in the box representing this entity type, which is comprised of the combination of properties (*SurveyNumber, QuestionNumber, PresentationOrder*). As you are well aware, a composite AK can be declared in a logical DDL design with the aid of a multi-column UNIQUE constraint (as I exemplified in the `SurveyQuestion` table that is part of the expository DDL layout expounded a few sections below).

**The *Response* entity type**

Yes, with the *Response* entity type I am depicting a *relationship between two other relationships*; it *may* seem awkward at first glance but there is nothing wrong with this approach, as long as it (a) represents the features of the business context of interest accurately and (b) is represented properly in a logical-level layout.

Yes, you are totally correct, it would be an error to portray that part of the scenario at the logical level of abstraction by means of two `Response.SurveyNumber` (or, say, `Response.SurveyId`) values referenced from two different columns in the same `Response` row.

## Derived logical SQL-DDL layout

```
-- You should determine which are the most fitting 
-- data types and sizes for all your table columns 
-- depending on your business context characteristics.

-- As one would expect, you are free to make use of 
-- your preferred (or required) naming conventions.

CREATE TABLE Person (
    PersonId        INT      NOT NULL,
    FirstName       CHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    LastName        CHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    GenderCode      CHAR(3)  NOT NULL,
    BirthDate       DATE     NOT NULL,
    CreatedDateTime DATETIME NOT NULL,
    --
    CONSTRAINT Person_PK PRIMARY KEY (PersonId),
    CONSTRAINT Person_AK UNIQUE      (
        FirstName,
        LastName,
        GenderCode,
        BirthDate
    )
);

CREATE TABLE Survey (
    SurveyNumber    INT       NOT NULL,
    Description     CHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    CreatedDateTime DATETIME  NOT NULL,
    --
    CONSTRAINT Survey_PK PRIMARY KEY (SurveyNumber),
    CONSTRAINT Survey_AK UNIQUE      (Description)
);

CREATE TABLE PersonSurvey (
    PersonId           INT      NOT NULL,
    SurveyNumber       INT      NOT NULL,
    RegisteredDateTime DATETIME NOT NULL,
    --
    CONSTRAINT PersonSurvey_PK         PRIMARY KEY (PersonId, SurveyNumber),
    CONSTRAINT PersonSurveyToPerson_FK FOREIGN KEY (PersonId)
        REFERENCES Person (PersonId),
    CONSTRAINT PersonSurveyToSurvey_FK FOREIGN KEY (SurveyNumber)
        REFERENCES Survey (SurveyNumber)
);

CREATE TABLE Question (
    QuestionNumber  INT       NOT NULL,
    Wording         CHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    CreatedDateTime DATETIME  NOT NULL,
    --
    CONSTRAINT Question_PK PRIMARY KEY (QuestionNumber),
    CONSTRAINT Question_AK UNIQUE      (Wording)
);

CREATE TABLE SurveyQuestion (
    SurveyNumber       INT      NOT NULL,
    QuestionNumber     INT      NOT NULL,
    PresentationOrder  TINYINT  NOT NULL,
    IsMandatory        BIT      NOT NULL,
    IntegratedDateTime DATETIME NOT NULL,
    --
    CONSTRAINT SurveyQuestion_PK PRIMARY KEY (SurveyNumber, QuestionNumber),
    CONSTRAINT SurveyQuestion_AK UNIQUE      (
        QuestionNumber,
        SurveyNumber,
        PresentationOrder
    ),
    CONSTRAINT SurveyQuestionToSurvey_FK   FOREIGN KEY (SurveyNumber)
        REFERENCES Survey   (SurveyNumber),
    CONSTRAINT SurveyQuestionToQuestion_FK FOREIGN KEY (QuestionNumber)
        REFERENCES Question (QuestionNumber)
);

CREATE TABLE Response (
    SurveyNumber     INT      NOT NULL,
    QuestionNumber   INT      NOT NULL,
    PersonId         INT      NOT NULL,
    Content          TEXT     NOT NULL,
    ProvidedDateTime DATETIME NOT NULL,
    --
    CONSTRAINT Response_PK                 PRIMARY KEY (SurveyNumber, QuestionNumber, PersonId),
    CONSTRAINT ResponseToPersonSurvey_FK   FOREIGN KEY (PersonId, SurveyNumber)
        REFERENCES PersonSurvey   (PersonId, SurveyNumber),
    CONSTRAINT ResponseToSurveyQuestion_FK FOREIGN KEY (SurveyNumber, QuestionNumber)
        REFERENCES SurveyQuestion (SurveyNumber, QuestionNumber)
);
```

**Two composite FOREIGN KEYs in the `Response` table**

This is, probably, the most important point to discuss: the references made from a given `Response` row to

1. `SurveyQuestion.SurveyNumber`, and
2. `SurveyPerson.SurveyNumber`

*must have matching values*. As far as I am concerned, the best option to enforce this condition in a declarative way is by making use of two composite FOREIGN KEYs (FKs).

As shown in the DDL design, the first FK is making a reference to the `PersonSurvey` table PRIMARY KEY (PK), i.e., `(PersonId, SurveyNumber)`, and is conformed by the columns `Response.PersonId` and `Response.SurveyNumber`.

The second FK is pointing to the `SurveyQuestion` table PK, i.e., `(SurveyNumber, QuestionNumber)`, and is, accordingly, made up of the columns `Response.SurveyNumber` and `Response.QuestionNumber`.

In this way, the `Response.SurveyNumber` column is quite instrumental since it is used as part of a FK reference in *two* different constraints.

With this method, one ensures database management system-guaranteed *referential integrity* from

- (a) `Response` to the `PersonSurvey`;
- (b) `Response` to the `SurveyQuestion`; and
- (c) each of the tables representing an associative entity type to the tables standing for independent entity types, namely `Person`, `Survey` and `Question`.

**Derived data to avoid update anomalies**

I have noticed in your diagram two elements that I esteem are worth mentioning. These elements are related to two `PersonSurvey` columns that can (should) be *derived*.

In that regard, you can derive the `PersonSurvey.IsStarted` datum by querying if a given `Person` occurrence has provided one or more `Responses` to `Questions` that integrate an exact `Survey` via the `SurveyQuestion` table.

And you can also obtain the `PersonSurvey.IsCompleted` data point by determining if a given `Person` instance has supplied a `Response` to all the `Questions` that cointain a value of 'TRUE' in the `IsMandatory` column in a specific `SurveyQuestion` row.

By way of the derivation of these values, you are preventing some update anomalies that would have eventually arisen in case you had kept such values in the `SurveyQuestion` column.

## Important consideration

As [@Dave](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/70109) rightly points out in his comment, if you face a future requirement demanding the management of different kinds of responses that imply managing dates, numeric values, multiple choice, and another possible aspects, you will have to extend this database layout.

Comment: Wow, this perfectly answered the question in my head and then taught me more!  Since comments should suggest improvements: It was slightly confusing that keys ended with both `ID` and `Number`, but otherwise this is fantastic.  Thank you.

Comment: @Zach You're most welcome, I'm glad the post helped you. Thanks for the feedback, some refinements are decidedly called for.

Answer (score 1):

This is one reason why I don't like to prefix columns when migrating them as foreign keys.  In your first case, the modeling tool may force you to prefix one of the `survey_id` columns in the `survey_person_question_response` table.  You may be able to adjust this after the relationship is made.

If necessary remove the redundant survey id field when you build the physical model where you don't need the duplicated column.  As you have identified, both your models have issues, but I believe the first model is better overall.

Comment: Thanks for the insight - I did collapse down to 1 column in the physical model which enforces everything I wanted.