# How to model a three-way association that involves Product, Category and Label?

Tags: mysql, database-design, foreign-key, primary-key, many-to-many

I have the following three tables:

```
products:
    product_id,
    product_name,
    ...

categories:
    category_id,
    category_name,
    category_parent_id,
    category_priority (for sort ordering),
    .....

labels:
    label_id,
    label_name,
    .....
```

The idea is that *products* assigned to a *category* will be grouped within each *category* by *labels* and listed on the website in this manner:

```
---label1---
product_1
product_2
product_3
---label2---
product_4
product_5
---label3---
product_6
product_7
product_8
product_9
etc.
```

I can’t figure out how to design an association table (or tables) that glue all this together and prevent anomalies like this:

```
---label1---
product_1
product_2
---label2---
product_2
product_3
```

At the same time, I’d like to allow a situation where there will be no *labels* assigned to a *category* when there are not enough *products* to justify it.

### Questions

Is it possible to design a structure that will hold it together or should I ‘abandon all hope’ and go with something like this:

```
categories:
    category_id,
    category_name,
    category_parent_id,
    categor_is_label,
    category_priority

products:
    product_id,
    product_name,
    ...
```

plus the association table that follows:

```
categories_products:
    category_id,
    product_id,
    priority
```

and handle all logic and checking for anomalies in the application?

I’m assuming that users won’t have direct access to the database.

### Comments and chat interactions

For those interested in an in-depth conversation about the business context at hand, you can visit [this chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46100/discussion-on-question-by-yemet-how-to-model-a-three-way-association-that-involv).

Comment: Discussion of this question has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46100/discussion-on-question-by-yemet-how-to-model-a-three-way-association-that-involv).

Answer (score 5):

<sub>***Note:** This answer presents an approach to cover specifically the business rules derived by way of the earliest series of comment and chat interactions (most of which can be seen in [this question revision](https://dba.stackexchange.com/revisions/150865/8)). Nevertheless, after more in-depth [clarifications and deliberations](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46100/discussion-on-question-by-yemet-how-to-model-a-three-way-association-that-involv) took place, [@yemet](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/106880/yemet) indicated that the business context may require a somewhat distinct method, due to the successive identification of dfferent business rules.*</sub>

---

The fact that you have determined that there exists a *three-way association* (also known as *ternary* or *diamond shaped* relationship) that involves the entity types (tables once implemented) of interest shows that you are heading in the right direction.

## Business rules

The objective should be to handle the three distinct relationships at hand separately, starting with a *logical level analysis* before considering the implementation aspects in full. In this regard, it is quite helpful to write down some formulations that describe the relevant *business rules*, e.g.:

First, for the following many-to-many (M:N) relationship:

- `A product is classified by one-to-many categories`
- `A category classifies zero-one-or-many products`

Which implies the existence of an *associative entity type* that I am going to call `product_category`.

Second, for a distinct M:N relationship:

- `A category is integrated by zero-one-or-many labels`
- `A label integrates zero-one-or-many categories`

Situation that suggests that there is another associative entity type, in this case the one  that I will name `category_label`.

Then, it is time to manage another M:N relationship, this time between the two associative entity types discussed above:

- `A product_category may receive zero-one-or-many label_assignments`
- `A category_label may take part in zero-one-or-many label_assignments`

As noted, I have included a new entity type that I denominated `label_assignment` but, naturally, you may name it using a term that is more meaningful with respect to your business domain.

I have assumed, based on the structure of the `categories` table contained in your question (specifically the column `categories.category_parent_id`), that there is a *self-recursive* one-to-many (1:M) relationship concerning the entity type called `category`. Later, you confirmed such situation, so the following rule applies as well:

- `A category comprises zero-one-or-many categories`

## Logical Model

Then I have derived an IDEF1X<sup>**1**</sup> logical model from the business rules formulations presented above, that is shown in [Figure 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tnd9e.jpg):

[image: Figure 1 - Product Classification Data Model]

With this arrangement you can solve much of your needs, since:

- Each *product* has to first be related to a certain *category* before it receives a *label assignment*.
- A *label* cannot be *assigned* to a particular *product* if it has not been connected to a certain *category* previously.
- A *product* can be related to a certain *category* without having to be involved in a relationship with a *label*.

## Expository DDL structure

Consequently, I coded the following DDL structure (tested on [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6f3b24)):

```
-- You should determine which are the most fitting 
-- data types and sizes for all your table columns 
-- depending on your business context characteristics.

-- As one would expect, you are free to make use of 
-- your preferred (or required) naming conventions.

CREATE TABLE product
(
     product_id       INT      NOT NULL,
     product_code     CHAR(30) NOT NULL,
     name             CHAR(30) NOT NULL,
     description      CHAR(90) NOT NULL,
     created_datetime DATETIME NOT NULL,
     CONSTRAINT PK_product             PRIMARY KEY (product_id),
     CONSTRAINT AK_product_code        UNIQUE      (product_code), -- (Possible?) ALTERNATE KEY.
     CONSTRAINT AK_product_name        UNIQUE      (name),         -- ALTERNATE KEY.
     CONSTRAINT AK_product_description UNIQUE      (description)   -- ALTERNATE KEY.
);

CREATE TABLE category
(
    category_number         INT      NOT NULL,
    parent_category_number  INT      NULL, -- Set up as ‘NULLable’, in order to focus on the main aspects of the approach exposed.
    name                    CHAR(30) NOT NULL,  
    description             CHAR(90) NOT NULL,
    created_datetime        DATETIME NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_category                         PRIMARY KEY (category_number),
    CONSTRAINT AK_category_name                    UNIQUE      (name),        -- ALTERNATE KEY.  
    CONSTRAINT AK_category_description             UNIQUE      (description), -- ALTERNATE KEY.
    CONSTRAINT FK_FROM_category_TO_parent_category FOREIGN KEY (parent_category_number)
        REFERENCES category  (category_number)
);

CREATE TABLE label
(
    label_number     INT      NOT NULL,
    name             CHAR(30) NOT NULL,    
    description      CHAR(90) NOT NULL,  
    created_datetime DATETIME NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_label             PRIMARY KEY (label_number),
    CONSTRAINT AK_label_name        UNIQUE      (name),       -- ALTERNATE KEY.
    CONSTRAINT AK_label_description UNIQUE      (description) -- ALTERNATE KEY.  
);

CREATE TABLE product_category -- Associative table.
(
    product_id          INT      NOT NULL,
    category_number     INT      NOT NULL, 
    classified_datetime DATETIME NOT NULL,  
    CONSTRAINT PK_product_category                  PRIMARY KEY (product_id, category_number),
    CONSTRAINT FK_FROM_product_category_TO_product  FOREIGN KEY (product_id)
        REFERENCES product  (product_id),
    CONSTRAINT FK_FROM_product_category_TO_category FOREIGN KEY (category_number)
        REFERENCES category (category_number)
);

CREATE TABLE category_label -- Associative table.
(
    category_number     INT      NOT NULL,
    label_number        INT      NOT NULL,   
    integrated_datetime DATETIME NOT NULL,  
    CONSTRAINT PK_category_label                  PRIMARY KEY (category_number, label_number),
    CONSTRAINT FK_FROM_category_label_TO_category FOREIGN KEY (category_number)
        REFERENCES category (category_number),
    CONSTRAINT FK_FROM_category_label_TO_label    FOREIGN KEY (label_number)
        REFERENCES label    (label_number)
);

CREATE TABLE label_assignment -- Associative table that ‘concretizes’ a relationship between two distinct relationships.
(
    product_id        INT       NOT NULL,
    category_number   INT       NOT NULL,
    label_number      INT       NOT NULL,  
    assigned_datetime DATETIME  NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_label_assignment                          PRIMARY KEY (product_id, category_number, label_number), -- Composite PRIMARY KEY.
    CONSTRAINT FK_FROM_label_assignment_TO_product_category FOREIGN KEY (product_id, category_number)   -- Composite FOREIGN KEY.
        REFERENCES product_category (product_id, category_number),
    CONSTRAINT FK_FROM_label_assignment_TO_category_label   FOREIGN KEY (category_number, label_number) -- Composite FOREIGN KEY.
        REFERENCES category_label   (category_number, label_number)
 );
```

Pay especial attention to the two composite FOREIGN KEY definitions of the `label_assignment` table, because the `category_number` attribute is included in both of them.

You brought up a requirement that stipulates that:

> A *product* has to be assigned to *category* in order to be visible in the shop.

Therefore, you should guarantee that each time that you INSERT a `product` row you as well *link* it with a certain `category` by means of the INSERTion of a row in the associative table here called `product_category`. In this way, both operations should be executed within the same [ACID TRANSACTION](http://amturing.acm.org/info/gray_3649936.cfm#add_1), so that they either succeed or fail as a *single unit*.

## Similar scenarios

You might find of help my answer to

- [Best data modelling approach to handle redundant foreign keys in relational model](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/120425/63644),

and also the [@Ypercubeᵀᴹ](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/993/ypercube%e1%b5%80%e1%b4%b9) answer to

- [Many to Many and Weak Entities](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/34050/63644).

---

## Endnote

<sub>**1.** Integration Definition for Information Modeling ([IDEF1X](http://www.idef.com/idef1x.htm)) is a highly recommendable data modeling technique that was established as a **standard** in december 1993 by the United States National Institute of Standards and Technology (NIST). It is solidly based on (a) theoretical work authored by the **originator** of the [Relational Model](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=362685), i.e., [Dr. E. F. Codd](http://amturing.acm.org/award_winners/codd_1000892.cfm); on (b) the [Entity-Relationship view](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=320440), developed by [Dr. P. P. Chen](http://awards.acm.org/award_winners/chen_6196475.cfm); and also on (c) the Logical Database Design Technique, created by Robert G. Brown. It is worth noting that IDEF1X was formalized by way of first-order logic.</sub>