# Modeling a three-way association with optional relation

Tags: database-design, mariadb, relations

### Business rules

I have three tables (**Parties**, **Categories** and **Products**) which representing the following relationships:

- A **product** is classified by zero-one-to-many **categories**
- A **category** classifies zero-one-or-many **products**

Then, I have the party relationships:

- A **product** is classified by one-to-one **party**
- A **party** classifies one-to-many **products**

In other words, a product doesn't have to be assigned a category, but they have to be assigned a party respectively.

The `party_id` for a **Category** must match the `party_id` for a **Product** in order to relate.

### EDIT

Following is a correction to the business rules above, based on @damir-sudarevic's solution proposal:

- `Category` is defined by a `party`.

  - *Each `category` is defined by exactly one `party`.*
  - *Each `party` may define more than one `category`.*
- `Product` is classified by a `party`.

  - *Each `product` is classified by exactly one `party`.*
  - *Each `party` may classify more than one `product`.*
- `Product` is classified in a `category` by a `party`.

  - *Each `product` may be classified in more than one `category`.*
  - *More than one `product` may be classified in the same `category`.*
  - *A `product` is classified by a `party` in a `category`, then that `category` is defined by that `party`*.

---

### Design proposals

I have based my first design on the proposal found [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/150865/how-to-model-a-three-way-association-that-involves-product-category-and-label), but it's not entirely applicable since I want to enforce `party_id` for both **Products** and **Categories** respectively *and* in the relation.

[image: Three-way association design proposal]

I have made a second proposal that simplifies the design somewhat, but I'm not sure how to enforce the `party_id` to the **Product**-**Category** relation.

[image]

---

### SQL based on latest design

Based on the comments and solution proposals, I have added a simplified SQL to create the tables and their relations.

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS parties (
  id INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (id));

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS categories (
  id INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  name_key VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  party_id INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  parent_id INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  PRIMARY KEY (id, party_id),
  INDEX fk_categories_parent_category_idx (parent_id ASC),
  UNIQUE INDEX name_key_UNIQUE (name_key ASC, party_id ASC),
  INDEX fk_categories_party_idx (party_id ASC),
  CONSTRAINT fk_categories_parent_category
    FOREIGN KEY (parent_id)
    REFERENCES categories (id)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT fk_categories_party
    FOREIGN KEY (party_id)
    REFERENCES parties (id)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS products (
  id INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  party_id INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  product_code VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id, party_id),
  UNIQUE INDEX product_code_UNIQUE (product_code ASC, party_id ASC),
  INDEX fk_products_party_idx (party_id ASC),
  CONSTRAINT fk_products_party
    FOREIGN KEY (party_id)
    REFERENCES parties (id)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS product_category (
  product_id INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  category_id INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  party_id INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (product_id, category_id),
  INDEX fk_product_category_product_idx (product_id ASC, party_id ASC),
  INDEX fk_product_category_category_idx (category_id ASC, party_id ASC),
  CONSTRAINT fk_product_category_product
    FOREIGN KEY (product_id , party_id)
    REFERENCES products (id , party_id)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT fk_product_category_category
    FOREIGN KEY (category_id , party_id)
    REFERENCES categories (id , party_id)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE);
```

---

### Question

How can I setup the three-way association table correctly to avoid the risk of having an application layer assigning a **product** to a **category** without enforcing the `party_id`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The `party_id` for a `Category` must match the `party_id` for a `Product` in order to relate.

Well, according to your wording of the problem, there is no need for `party_id` in `Category`.
The confusion likely stems from imprecise wording, you are blending predicate and constraints in one sentence.
For example:

> - A product is classified by one-to-one party.
> - A party classifies one-to-many products.

Can be worded more clearly:

- `Product` is classified by `party`.
- *Each `product` is classified by exactly one `party`.*
- *Each `party` may classify more than one `product`.*

This wording then directly leads to a usable model (predicate, *constraints*).

---

#### Option 1

```
-- Party PTY exists.
--
party {PTY}
   PK {PTY}
```

*Each product is classified by exactly one party;
for each party, that party may classify more than one product.*

```
-- Product PRO, classified by party PTY exists.
--
product {PRO, PTY}
     PK {PRO}

FK {PTY} REFERENCES party {PTY}
```

```
-- Category CAT exists.
--
category {CAT}
      PK {CAT}
```

*For each product, that product may be classified in more than one category. For each category, more than one product may be classified as belonging to that category.*

```
-- Product PRO is classified in category CAT.
--
product_category {PRO, CAT}
              PK {PRO, CAT}

FK1 {PRO} REFERENCES product  {PRO}
FK2 {CAT} REFERENCES category {CAT}
```

---

#### Option 2

It may be that a product is known before the matching party is known. Then a variation:

```
-- Party PTY exists.
--
party {PTY}
   PK {PTY}
```

```
-- Product PRO exists.
--
product {PRO}
     PK {PRO}
```

```
-- Product PRO is classified by party PTY.
--
product_party {PRO, PTY}
           PK {PRO}

FK1 {PRO} REFERENCES product {PRO}
FK2 {PTY} REFERENCES party   {PTY}
```

```
-- Category CAT exists.
--
category {CAT}
      PK {CAT}
```

```
-- Product PRO is classified in category CAT.
--
product_category {PRO, CAT}
              PK {PRO, CAT}

FK1 {PRO} REFERENCES product_party {PRO}

FK2 {CAT} REFERENCES category {CAT}
```

---

### EDIT

After few comments:

- `Category` is defined by a `party`.

  - *Each `category` is defined by exactly one `party`.*
  - *Each `party` may define more than one `category`.*
- `Product` is classified by a `party`.

  - *Each `product` is classified by exactly one `party`.*
  - *Each `party` may classify more than one `product`.*
- `Product` is classified in a `category` by a `party`.

  - *Each `product` may be classified in more than one `category`.*
  - *More than one `product` may be classified in the same `category`.*
  - *If a `product` is classified by a `party` in a `category`, then that `category` is defined by that `party`*.

---

### Option 3

*Party* must exists before *category* and *product*.

```
-- Party PTY exists.
--
party {PTY}
   PK {PTY}


-- Product PRO, classified by party PTY exists.
--
product {PRO, PTY}
     PK {PRO}
     SK {PRO, PTY}

     FK {PTY} REFERENCES party {PTY}


-- Category CAT, defined by party PTY exists.
--
category {CAT, PTY}
      PK {CAT}
      SK {CAT, PTY}

      FK {PTY} REFERENCES party {PTY}


-- Product PRO is classified in category CAT
-- by party PTY.
--
product_category {PRO, CAT, PTY}
              PK {PRO, CAT}

      FK1 {PRO, PTY} REFERENCES product  {PRO, PTY}
      FK2 {CAT, PTY} REFERENCES category {CAT, PTY}
```

---

### Option 4

If *product* and *category* can exist independently of *party*.

```
-- Party PTY exists.
--
party {PTY}
   PK {PTY}


-- Product PRO exists.
--
product {PRO}
     PK {PRO}


-- Category CAT exists.
--
category {CAT}
      PK {CAT}


-- Product PRO is classified by party PTY.
--
product_party {PRO, PTY}
           PK {PRO}
           SK {PRO, PTY}

      FK1 {PRO} REFERENCES product {PRO}
      FK2 {PTY} REFERENCES party   {PTY}


-- Category CAT is defined by party PTY.
--
category_party {CAT, PTY}
            PK {CAT}
            SK {CAT, PTY}

      FK1 {CAT} REFERENCES category {CAT}
      FK2 {PTY} REFERENCES party    {PTY}


-- Product PRO is classified in category CAT
-- by party PTY.
--
product_category {PRO, CAT, PTY}
              PK {PRO, CAT}

                 FK1 {PRO, PTY} REFERENCES
      product_party  {PRO, PTY}

                 FK2 {CAT, PTY} REFERENCES
      category_party {CAT, PTY}
```

---

Note:

```
All attributes (columns) NOT NULL

PK = Primary Key
AK = Alternate Key   (Unique)
SK = Proper Superkey (Unique)
FK = Foreign Key
```

Comment: Thank you @damir-sudarevic. As mentioned in the comment to @rickc, I have missed out some details in my question which will be added. Both answers have been very helpful and made me realize there are details to be considered which are not yet mentioned in my original question. One example is that the `party_id` is scoped in the **Categories** table, meaning that the nested sets (left and right) are calculated using `party_id`.

Comment: @Jonah, added options 3 and 4 deal with `category` and `party`.

Comment: Original question updated to reflect a more correct definition of the business rules as well as a SQL simplified code to test out the solution proposal above. It seems to work fine, but I just need to figure out how to select `Products` both with and without a `Category` assigned. Possibly through a `LEFT JOIN` of `product_category`and `products`.

Comment: do you mind providing an example and/or link to the definition of "proper superkey"? I want to ensure that I have understood your **Option 3** correctly in terms of e.g. `SK {PRO, PTY}`. Thank you

Comment: @Jonah (1/3) super-set of a `KEY`, having at least one element more. Logically not needed, but SQL needs it to allow for `FK` target. `KEY` is a short for a *candidate key* a minimal, irreducible superkey.

Comment: @Jonah (2/3) Wikipedia is OK, also see any book *C. J. Date*.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superkey

Comment: @Jonah (3/3) in SQL simply make it `unique`.

Comment: Thank you. The term was new to me but looked like a composite key. Answer accepted.

Answer (score 1):

Using your Model #1, I believe the database itself can be made to enforce the stated constraints (i.e., a **category** and a **product** may only be related when they are both related to the same **party**) using the following constraints.

- The primary key for **category_party** consists of **category_id** and **party_id**. This creates an optional many-to-many relationship between **categories** and **parties**. This implies the following.

  - A **category** is classified by zero-one-to-many **parties**.
  - A **party** classifies zero-one-to-many **categories**.
- The primary key for **product_party** consists of **product_id** and **party_id**. This creates an optional many-to-many relationship between **categories** and **parties**. This implies the following.

  - A **product** is classified by zero-one-to-many **parties**. This will be overridden below to meet your stated requirements.
  - A **party** is classified by zero-one-to-many **products**.
- There is unique constraint on **product_id** in the **product_party**. This makes the relationship between **party** and **product** a one-to-many instead of many-to-many. This implies the following.

  - A **product** is classified by one-to-one **party**, overriding the previously-stated cardinality of this relationship.
- The primary key of **product_category_assignment** consists of **category_id**, **product_id** and **party_id**.
- The foreign key from **product_category_assignment** to **category_party** consists of **category_id** and **party_id**
- The foreign key from **product_category_assignment** to **product_party** consists of **product_id** and **party_id**
- The constraint that a **category** and a **product** can only be related when they are related to a common **party** is enforced because **product_category_assignment** only contains one **party_id** which is used in both foreign key relationships.

I believe that the only requirement not covered here is that a **product** is ***required*** to have a related **party** (i.e., **party** is not optional).

Using Model #2 would require much more code (i.e., an ugly stored procedure?) to enforce the constraint because the **structure** of the database will allow the following.

- The **category** can be have one **party_id** (e.g., 1).
- The **product** can have a different **party_id** (e.g., 2).
- The **product_category** can have yet a third **party_id** (e.g., 3).

I do want to point out that there appear to be some *unstated* requirements here that could have some minor bearing on my answer above. For example...

- What is the correct cardinality of the relationship between **category** and **party**? The two models you presented are different in this respect.

  - Model #1 allows a **category** to be related to zero, one or many **parties**.
  - Model #2 only allows for zero or one **party** for each **category**.
- Is a **category** required to have (at least) one **party** or is that relationship optional? This is not clear from your description or either of your models.

I have always said that there are three things that are important in a data model: details, *DeTaiLs* and ***DETAILS***. Sometimes nailing down the details of every relationship around the complexity can help you discover the best way to design the data model. Sometimes, complex relationships like this may point to missing entities (tables). Sometimes, complex requirements defy enforcement using only database structural constraints and require a bit of code (e.g., a stored procedure?) to finish the job.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you! The model is still in design phase, so I realize that I have missed out a few details in my question and the mistakes in Model #2. Your suggestions to Model #1 is definitely the way to go. To answer your questions on the unstated requirements, a **category** should only relate to one party. This is valid for Model #2 too of course and should be applied to **party** as well. I will amend my initial question and test above changes shortly.