# Is it possible to enforce corresponding hierarchies?

Tags: database-design, foreign-key, constraint, relational-theory

I constructed the following toy example to illustrate my question.

The left side of the schema describes a an abstract product consisting of its parts.

The right side of the schema describes actual produced instances of these products/parts. The horizontal relations indicate from which "template" the instance was built. Note that it is possible that a `part_instance` is initially not yet assigned to a `product_instance`.

[image]

**Here's the challenge:**

Assigning a `part_instance` to a `product_instance` should only be possible if the `part` from which the `part_instance` was built is actually a part of the `product` from which `product_instance` was built from. So the (optional) hierarchy on the right should be enforced to correspond to the hierarchy on the left.

Or as an example: Let's assume *part1* belongs to *product1* and *part2* belongs to *product2*. Now let's create *productInstance1* linked to *product1*, *productInstance2* linked to *product2*, *partInstance1* linked to *part1* and *partInstance2* linked to *part2*. It should be allowed to assign *partInstance1* to *productInstance1*, but not to *productInstance2*. Similarly it should be allowed to assign *partInstance2* to *productInstance2* but not to *productInstance1*.

**Question:**

Is it possible to enforce this rule in the database?

Comment: Can't you just add the `instance_id` to the `product_instance` and `part_instance` to bind them to the certain instance at the top of hierarcy?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Look at these questions and answers: [database-design diamond" scheme](https://dba.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A993+diamond)

Comment: Also check this excellent and detailed answer by 1750 in a similar problem: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/120246/best-data-modelling-approach-to-handle-redundant-foreign-keys-in-a-database-abou/120425#120425

Comment: Thank you both for your inputs. I think I figured it out based on that information and I posted it as an answer. Feel free to comment on my answer if you feel like that can be improved further.

Comment: Yes , nice one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the comments to my question it looks like the solution is to add `product_id` to the primary key of both the `part` and `product_instance` tables.

[image]

Comment: Don't forget to mark your answer as the solution. It will help others looking at the question